# restful way of routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Is there a better way to write such routs in rails 3 ?
I converted my application from rails 2 to rails 3 .

match "/resume/education/edit_education",
      :controller => "resume/education#edit_education",
      :as=>"resume_edit_education"

```
match "/resume/education/update_education",
  :controller => "resume/education#update_education",
  :as=>"resume_update_education"

match "/resume/education/cancel_education_add",
  :controller => "resume/education#cancel_education_add",
  :as=>"resume_cancel_education_add"

match  "/resume/education/cancel_education_edit",
  :controller => "resume/education#cancel_education_edit",
  :as=>"resume_cancel_education_edit"

match  "/resume/education/remove_education",
  :controller => "resume/education#remove_education",
  :as=>"resume_remove_education"

match  "/resume/education/update_education_title",
  :controller => "resume/education#update_education_title",
  :as=>"resume_update_education_title"

match "/resume/education/move_up",
  :controller => "resume/education#move_up",
  :as=>"resume_education_move_up"

match  "/resume/education/move_down",
  :controller => "resume/education#move_down",
  :as=>"resume_education_move_down"

match "/resume/education/remove",
  :controller => "resume/education#remove",
  :as=>"resume_remove_education"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should refactor your controller like this

```
class Resume::EducationController

  def cancel_add
  end

  def cancel_edit
  end

  def update_title
  end

  def move_up
  end

  def move_down
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

end
```

Then you could organize your routes thus

```
namespace :resume do
  resource :education, :only => [:update, :destroy] do
    collection do
      get 'cancel_add'
      get 'cancel_update'
      get 'update_title'
      get 'move_up' # get -> put ?
      get 'move_down'
    end
  end
end
```

Look to guide [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)